# Custom url structure - pages under a custom post type

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I'm struggling with the structure of my Wordpress site and I was hoping you might be able to give me some advice.

The site is for a series of events and the structure is as follows:

- Gateway (contains a list of events)

  - London 2012 (a specific event)

    - Overview (default for event)
    - Speakers
    - Agenda
    - Venue
    - Register
  - New York 2012

    - Overview
    - Speakers
    - Agenda
    - Venue
    - Register

I am using several custom post types, and each have a number of custom fields attached:

Events: the information from this custom post type is used to create the Overview page
Speakers: this a pool of the potential speakers. Speakers are added to a specific event using the above custom post type
Venue: this is a pool of potential venues. The venue is added to a specific event using the above custom post type

I would like the structure of the site to be as follows:

- / - Gateway
- /london-2012/ - A specific event overview
- /london-2012/speakers - Speakers page
- /london-2012/agenda - Agenda page
- /new-york-2012/speakers - Another speakers page
- etc.

…where an identical page 'types' (eg. speakers page) will all use the same template across the board (I'll just get the parent event from the URL and do a custom query to grab the data for the page).

Can anyone suggest the best way to do this? I believe either a URL rewrite solution or categories may work but I'm unsure about both :(

**Update 1**

Have sorted this using redirects - for example, speakers pages:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
  '^event/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/speakers/?$', //Checked against the global $wp object - $wp->request
  'index.php?page_id=9&event_slug=$matches[1]', //Use WP_Query params to find your page
  'top' //This will superceed the default WP rewrite stack
);
```

then registered the variable:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars');

function my_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = 'event_slug';
    return $vars;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
example.com/event/london-2012/speakers/john-doe
```

You need an "event" post type and a "speaker post type. The event post type should be hierarchical and should have a sub-page called "speakers" which should use a custom template that displays all the "speaker" post types assigned to that event (see the Posts 2 Posts plugin).

Then you can create other sub-pages like agenda, register, etc.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me :)

I've created a new hierarchical post type called 'Event', can I make this a parent of a page though? I didn't know that you could cross-match parent-child post types?

Comment: Your event can BE the parent: `/event/sub-page`. But you can create post-to-post relationships with Posts 2 Posts plugin if you wanted speakers to be associated with events and vice versa.